# better alternative to flake8's "E902 TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement"

Tags: python, flake8

I do understand the E902 error, however I do think it's a bit "messy". This is for 2 reasons:

- It feels to me that it should be F902 (a failure rather than an error). After all, as I see it in Flake's world, errors are things that are wrong in the style guide (e.g. having 3 newlines in a row), whereas Failures are things that will not make the program run (e.g. referencing a variable before declaration). In other words, when I save a python file in my IDE, I should be happy to ignore any errors (as long as I'm just hacking away), but want to be alerted of anything that is obviously a mistake (and not just me not caring about things). Obviously writing not valid python is *even worse* than using a variable before declaring it (which in some cases, will actually run).
- More importantly, I feel that it's very unhelpful that this error always points to line 1 character 1. This means it's up to me to start looking in the code (of files sometimes 1000s lines long) to the exact spot where I forgot to close a parenthesis, or run another tool (such as just running `python` on the file) to find the exact line. Also, this means that my editor (VIM) will not show any error for the line I'm working on; I will only see the error if I scroll up all the way.

I guess my questions are threefold:

- Why is E902 an error instead of a failure (not super important, but if there's a rationale behind it' I'd be happy to learn it)
- Is there a good reason that E902 error is always on line 1 col 1, or is this just that not enough resources have been spent (yet) to have it point to the right spot in the code).
- Most importantly: is there an accepted / better way for this? Perhaps a wrapper around flake8 that, in case of a E902 error uses some other way to find a more accurate spot (note that pyflakes, which is part of flake8, does find the correct line; probably not a good idea to run `python` since there does not seem to be a way to tell python to only parse the file but not actually run it.). I'm sure I can create such a wrapper myself, but if other/smarter people already made one, I'd prefer to reuse their work.

For completeness, the following code shows the issue:

```
def x():
    pass


x(
a = 1
b = 2
```

Both pyflakes and python show an error in line 7 (which at least is very close to where the error is made), whereas flake8 will just show the error on 1:1

Comment: Seems to me this feedback would be better suited as an issue on flake8's GitHub? https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8

Comment: You make a good point. I should probably post the first 2 questions/issues there (should and will do so). The third one (asking for other tools / wrapper scripts / etc) probably belongs here.

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer ; I did dive a bit deeper, answering questions 1 and 2 myself now (surprising how I failed to see these answers before; probably because I searched github for information, even though the issues are on gitlab ). The error seems to be a result of python's tokenizer; which actually reports the error on the last line (makes sense, that's where the EOF is): https://gitlab.com/pycqa/flake8/-/issues/655 . The `Fxxx` error codes range are actually pyFlakes error (not failures). The `E` in `Exxx` does stand for error.... That leaves just the final question.

Answer (score 4):

answering all three of the questions (usually separate questions should be separate questions on SO but...):

1. the E / F / W codes do not mean error / failure / warning -- the prefix is a coincidence.  F codes come from pyflakes, E and W codes come from pycodestyle (though there are two special E codes inherited from pycodestyle that remain -- E902 and E999 for OSError and SyntaxError -- I'd love to change this but the sheer number of people using flake8 makes breaking changes tricky)
2. it is col 1 line 1 because this error comes from the tokenizer and it reports the error out-of-bounds on the last line of the file.  the tokenizer is not very good about giving precise error locations
3. it is considered a bug, but nobody has volunteered to work on it yet, if I'm reading it correctly it should be a 2 line fix -- you can read more about the bug here: https://github.com/PyCQA/flake8/issues/740

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer